# Altering CSV file to change order or data printed

Tags: python, jython, jes

The function below takes a csv file that is formatted grade type,grade type number,grade. Example the first 10 are assignment,assignment number,grade. The function puts these first 10 into a list.

at the moment it print in the order assigment,assigment number,grade but im trying to get it to print in order of grade,assigment,assigment number.

```
def assigment(file):
    res = []
    f = open(file,'r+')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
      if i < 10:  
        res.append((line[0],int(line[1]),int(line[2])))

        res.sort(key= lambda x: x[2])

    max = res[-1]
    min = res[0]

    print max
    print min
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `key=lambda x: x[2]` can be replaced with `operator.itemgetter(2)`. Also `for i, line in enumerate(reader): if i < 10:` with `for line in itertools.islice(reader, 10):`.

Comment: Why are you iterating over the whole CVS if you're using only the first 10 lines? `break` when `i` reaches 10. Also why are you sorting `res` after every `append`, why not just one time at the end?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of ordering in your output data. One is the order of items in each row, and the other is the order of the rows.

The order of items in each row is controlled by the line

`res.append(( . . .`

To modify this order, just change the order of subexpressions in this line.

To modify the ordering of the lines, a very nice approach is to sort repeatedly.  Sort first by the least important criterion and last by the most important criterion.

If you want to sort by the element 0 of each row, breaking ties by the value of element 1, and breaking any remaining ties by the value of element 2, have three lines of sorting in your code rather than just 1, for example:

```
res.sort(key= lambda x: x[2])
res.sort(key= lambda x: x[1])
res.sort(key= lambda x: x[0])
```

or some equivalent. Python sorting is "stable", so for example, the final sorting step leaves the existing ordering in place if the keys for the final sort are the same.

Comment: Why sort this three times, instead of just once with a multi-value (tuple) key?

Comment: @Cristian A tuple key would probably be the more sophisticated approach. It seems to me that for maximum performance you would want to add the key to each record in the dataset, then sort, then extract just the desired data. This seemed simpler to explain, and it seemed doubtful that performance is a key goal in Terr's situation.